# how to remove space between flex-item on flex-wrap: wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, styles, tailwind-css

```
    <div class="flex flex-wrap items-baseline">
      <div class="h-10 basis-1/2 border bg-orange-500">hello1</div>
      <div class="h-40 basis-1/2 border bg-amber-700">hello4</div>
      <div class="h-20 basis-1/2 border bg-yellow-500">hello2</div>
      <div class="h-30 basis-1/2 border bg-green-800">hello3</div>
    </div>
```

problem preview image: https://i.ibb.co/SK6zPCv/image.png

code: https://play.tailwindcss.com/AI0Uo1vVsT

Answer (score -1):

You can use grid to get more control of your layout. Or you can add custom css like:

```css
.h-20{
  position: relative;
  top:-7.5rem;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To arrange elements in both rows and columns, you must use grid, because according to the definition of flex, it can only be used to arrange elements in one dimension, but by using grid, this problem can be easily solved.

[example](https://miro.medium.com/max/860/1*FifZUGz97Onmb7RUOairbg.png)